# Missing objective for Assassin's Creed 2

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-2

I've been playing through Assassin's Creed 2 and am on Sequence 13 where you must kill the 9 lieutenants. I've killed 8 of them and suddenly the final objective marker for the 9th has disappeared. It was there before I killed the 8th. I've climbed every tower, so there isn't any area I haven't explored. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Alternatively, is there a way to recover one of the past save files so I don't have to start from scratch?

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any active objective markers?

Comment: @svavil, none whatsoever. And it still says 8/9 lieutenants killed in the upper left corner, so the mission is not complete.

Comment: The game allows to turn the display of certain group of markers on and off. Can you check if quest markers are set to display?

Comment: @svavil, thanks for the reply. I should have pointed out I'm on PC, which doesn't have the toggle option I don't think. If so, how do you do that? Google is failing me on this one.

Comment: I used to play it on PC several years ago, and I think I was able to toggle marker display in the map menu. Will reinstall the game and try to reproduce it in a couple of days.

Comment: I decided to try downloading another save file from [this website](http://www.assassinscreedsavegames.com/savegames/Assassin%60s_Creed_II) and can't see objectives on that either. I also reinstalled the game (keeping my save file in a separate folder during the install) with no luck. Also tried leaving the Florence city through a quick travel and coming back and... **SUCCESS!!!** That's what worked apparently. Thanks anyway for the help, @svavil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

I ended up leaving the Florence city and coming back through a quick travel booth, which appears to have restored the objective marker.

**Other things I tried without success:**

I decided to try downloading another save file from [this website](http://www.assassinscreedsavegames.com/savegames/Assassin%60s_Creed_II) and can't see objectives on that either. I also reinstalled the game (keeping my save file in a separate folder during the install) with no luck. Oh well, the above solution worked.

Comment: Wow, seems like a strange issue. Glad you have it resolved, though.